# How do I move (a) file(s) from Windows to headless Ubuntu Server without retaining the original copy(ies) in Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, scp, lan

question title pretty much sums it up but for more background; I set up an Ubuntu Server to host Plex on for myself and family members. Currently to add movies I will extract files from a disc or download them (legally of course) and use SCP from my laptop running Windows to transfer them over LAN. This works just fine but it doesn’t *move* the file(s), it makes a *copy* of them to the server so I still have to delete the original file upon completion. I have searched everywhere for a solution to make this function more as a cut/paste than copy/paste to no avail and I am just curious what experiences others have had.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options:

1. Mount the ubuntu server's filesystem onto your laptop.  This will probably involve installing and configuring [samba](https://www.samba.org) to provide SMB/CIFS network file shares (I only say "probably" because there are other network file system options, but CIFS is native to Windows and is the best option for Windows clients)

   Then you can "move" files onto it.

   Note, however, that because you're moving file(s) from one filesystem to another, "move" is actually "copy then delete".
2. Write a script (.bat file or powershell script or whatever) that copies the file(s) with `scp` and then deletes it/them if the copy was successful.

   This is a lot simpler than setting up samba and probably your best option unless you already need the server's filesystem mounted on your laptop for other reasons.

---

A third option just occurred to me. It's possible that there are GUI `scp` or `sftp` clients for Windows that can do "move" (i.e. copy and delete) in one drag-and-drop or cut-and-paste operation.  I don't know of any (I don't use Windows), but it might be worth your while searching for one.  Maybe ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

And another: it looks like `sshfs` has been implemented for Windows.  https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win - this is probably a lot more hassle to set up than samba, and almost certainly performs much worse than samba (i.e. slower).  For a start, it requires first installing [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and [Winfsp](https://github.com/winfsp/winfsp) (a clone of [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) for Windows).

Comment: There used to be an SCP file system implementation called swish; don't know whether that still works

Comment: Ah, actually sftp, not only SCP, but it's pretty dead: https://github.com/alamaison/swish